# How to insert date and time with fractional seconds in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, datetime

I'm using oracle 11g.
I'm inserting date and time using function `SYSDATE` into column with type `TIMESTAMP`. But fractional seconds always are 0. 
How can I insert date and time of database server with fractional seconds? Is there any functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SYSTIMESTAMP` instead of `SYSDATE`.